# What is the right way to configure global authentication http headers in Angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, auth0

I'm trying to add JWT-based authentication in an Angular 2 application.

I have received an idToken from Auth0 and stored it in LocalStorage. Now I want to ensure, that all outgoing http calls to my API will have this header setup:

Authorization: Bearer e3rere....

Of course I can manually add it on every http call. But it would be more convenient to configure it once and for all.

What is the right way of doing that in Angular? (Angular 2)

Comment: Actually Angular 2.x? If you're using 4.3 and above you can use the new `HttpClient` and implement an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses). Otherwise, it's common to subclass `Http` or [the request options](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options) and use DI to inject your own version. Both approaches are already documented elsewhere.

Comment: Thx @jonrsharpe I tried following the mentioned article on request options https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options but the headers do not seem to be added as expected. I will now try using the interceptors mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I added a method to my AuthService, which handled creating the headers

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    //Other stuff your authentication service might do

    getHeaderWithAuthorization() {
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.Token) {

            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.Token);
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }
}


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private baseUrl;
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthenticationService)             
{
        this.baseUrl = "/api/User/";
        this.options = authService.getHeaderWithAuthorization();
    }

    SaveUser(user) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "SaveUser", user, this.options)
            .map((res) => res.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx for sharing. But this is kind of what I tried to avoid as I will need to repeat the code in all my services.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

If you're using angular 4.3+, then you can create an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) for this purpose which will act as an intermediary.

**Note:** In order to use the interceptor you've to use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) instead of [Http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) service which is a new addition from angular 4.3 that will give you [some benefits](http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Jul/15/angular-http-client.html) over Http service.

There you can add your header if the user is logged in.

```
@Injectable()
export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       if(UserService.getToken()){
         req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserService.getToken());
       }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Important: don't forget to provide the interceptor class in your app module .

```
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AddHeaderInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
```

**Approach 2:**

If you're using lower version than 4.3.0 then you can adapt a different approach something like extending the BaseRequestOptions to inject common headers to all requests.

```
   import {BaseRequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
   @Injectable()
   export class AdddingHeaderOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
        constructor() {
            super();
            if(UserService.getToken()){
                this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserService.getToken());
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, you can provide it to the app module file.

```
@NgModule({
    providers   : [
        {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AdddingHeaderOptions }
    ]
})
```

Comment: You should note that this only works for newer versions of Angular; `@angular/common/http` was introduced in 4.3.0, and many apps will be using `@angular/http`.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case I think it might be a bigger change. So I will go back and use a wrapper class around http instead then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be considered the optimal solution but I found it pretty useful.

I added this function to app.module.ts:

```
 export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions, auth: AuthService) {
   return new AuthHttp( new AuthConfig(
       {
         tokenName: 'id_token',
         globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
         tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token'))
       }
     ), http, options);
 }
...
providers: [...{
  provide: AuthHttp,
  useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
  deps: [ Http, RequestOptions, AuthService ]
},...]
```

and then finally I would make sure that my services depends on AuthHttp instead of Http.